# Java SystemLookAndFeel on Xubuntu

Tags: java, swing

I am using

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

inside a try-catch block to ensure my Swing application looks 'native' on each platform. This has always worked on linux, Mac and Windows. I have just got a new machine running Xubuntu and whilst this statement does not cause errors, my GUI does not like native; instead looks like the Java (metal?) theme. Is this a problem with my OS and what could I do to fix it? The same program appears to run fine and look native on Windows and Mac.

Thanks

Comment: Also see [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=771396)

Comment: Thanks for that reply - interesting reading. I tried all the suggestions, none of them worked :-(. At least it confirms I'm not going mad and this is a genuine bug of some sort...

Comment: I do not run XUbuntu myself so I cannot try it out :-(

Answer (score 2):

Use the source Luke :)
if you look at the source of UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()
you will see a check for gnome desktop, which is not the case when running Xubuntu, Xubuntu is not running gnome but xfce desktop enviroment